# Resize html IMG for a JS window.print()

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, image

I currently have a print option on my website, I'm using @media hidden to hide specific elements, how would i go about changing an image size in the @media when my javascript print function is called?
I can easily change a normal div element, but I call an image from php like this:

```
<tr>

<td id="tdimg" width='200px' align='center'>
<?
if ($obituary['photo']!="")
        if (file_exists("../photos/".$obituary['photo']))
            echo"<img src='../photos/".$obituary['photo']."?".strtotime($obituary['addedon'])."' style='height:auto;width:180px;' border='0'>";
```

I can't figure out how to edit the image size here when window.print is called.
Im using this as the print code:

```
<a style="text-decoration:none" href="javascript:;" onclick="printFunction()">
    <img src="../images/print.png" alt="Print" />
</a>
```

This is my @media

```
@media print { 
           #share-buttons { 
              visibility: hidden; 
           }
           #flowersButton {
               visibility: hidden;
           }
           td img{
              width:600px;
           }

        }
```

Any helps greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

CSS always uses the closest style, meaning inline styles (such as `style="..."`) override page styles ( such as `.myclass { ... }`).

In this case the inline width that you have on the image `style='height:auto; width:180px;'` overrides the media query `td img{width:600px;}`.

What you can do is: 
 1. Remove the inline styling and then 
 2. Above the media query add `td img{height:auto; width:180px;}`

[Read more about](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#:~:text=A)%20Overriding%20inline%20styles,latter%20to%20override%20the%20former.) specificity in css.